# SQL join QUERY multiple tables and SELECT's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I build the following query,

```
        SELECT
        posts.id,
        posts.useraid,
        posts.useradn,
        posts.title,
        posts.createdate,
        posts.forumid,
        posts.type,
        posts.totalreplys,
        users.photo AS creatorphoto
    FROM posts
    JOIN users ON(users.id = posts.useraid)
    WHERE posts.forumid IN(
        SELECT subscribe.forumid AS fsub
        FROM subscribe  
        WHERE subscribe.useraid = '$myid'
    ) AND
    posts.forumid IN(
        SELECT forums.id
        FROM forums
        WHERE forums.relatedto=fsub
    )
    AND posts.type='post' 
    ORDER BY posts.timee DESC LIMIT 20
```

The code works perfectly without this part

```
AND
    posts.forumid IN(
        SELECT forums.id
        FROM forums
        WHERE forums.relatedto=fsub
    )
```

But, I need the query to select all posts from all forums he subscribe to, including the subforums posts.

Comment: You are not selecting fsub on your main query and that's why you can't relate to it, you are just using it in a subquery.

Comment: Is i as simple as adding quotes aroung 'fsub'?

Comment: '$myid' will not give you value of the variable. you need to use double quotes

Comment: Try replacing `forums.relatedto=fsub` with `forums.relatedto=posts.forumid`

Comment: Important if this is in PHP you should use ".$myid." in the query.

Comment: all wronge answers, sry.

Comment: Why sorry. What did you get?

Comment: nothing changed, the '$myid'  works.

Comment: Not sure but change `WHERE forums.relatedto=fsub` INTO `WHERE forums.relatedto = '$myid'`

Comment: did you read what im trying to do? I need the query to select from subforums too.

Comment: What is fsub? You can not use it in a next subquery this way.

Answer (score 0):

'fsub' has no scope here, it doesn't really even exist at this point in your query:

```
posts.forumid IN(
    SELECT forums.id
    FROM forums
    WHERE forums.relatedto=fsub
)
```

You need to use a UNION I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sub-queries why don't you just add the subscribe and forums table to the main FROM criteria?

e.g.,

```
FROM posts
JOIN users ON(users.id = posts.useraid)
JOIN subscribe ON (posts.forumid = subscribe.forumid)
JOIN forums ON (forums.relatedto = posts.forumid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT
        posts.id,
        posts.useraid,
        posts.useradn,
        posts.title,
        posts.createdate,
        posts.forumid,
        posts.`type`,
        posts.totalreplys,
        users.photo AS creatorphoto
    FROM posts
    JOIN users 
    ON users.id = posts.useraid AND posts.`type`='post'
    JOIN subscribe
    ON subscribe.forumid = posts.forumid AND subscribe.useraid = '$myid'
    JOIN forums
    ON posts.forumid = forums.relatedto 
    ORDER BY posts.timee DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: doesnt work... i cant see how the second select doing subforums querty posts

Comment: I tried that, but the query doesnt select posts from sub forums

Comment: @user2124281 Also, my new version?

Comment: Are the sub forums post in the post table? Or are they in another table?

Comment: @user2124281 can you post you table structure and perhaps some sample data.

Comment: I've tried to add UNION INTO THE SUBQUERY.
UNION
SELECT forums.id
FROM forums
WHERE forums.relatedto = fsub ..... if i put the forumid into fsub (1) its work.

Comment: @user2124281 I can help you, but I need to know the relations between your tables.

Comment: do you have skype? its really not comfortable to do it here

Comment: I don't have skype. Try to post a dump of you tables. SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename.

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer, you need first join the subscribe and forms before search it with subquery.

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.useraid,
    posts.useradn,
    posts.title,
    posts.createdate,
    posts.forumid,
    posts.type,
    posts.totalreplys,
    users.photo AS creatorphoto
FROM posts
JOIN users ON(users.id = posts.useraid)
WHERE posts.forumid IN(
    SELECT subscribe.forumid AS fsub
    FROM subscribe ,forums
    WHERE subscribe.useraid = '$myid'
    and forums.relatedto = subscribe.forumid
    and forums.id = subscribe.forumid     
) 
AND posts.type='post' 
ORDER BY posts.timee DESC LIMIT 20
```